# jQuery auto refresh every minute based on current rest second time

Tags: jquery

I have an jQuery Auto Refresh my data. I'm running it every 60 seconds/1 minute.

```
setInterval(function()
{
    //if every 60 seconds based on current time (count the rest of second from current time) then run the AJAX.
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "chkProfile.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:
        {
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (jsonStr)
        {
        }
    })
},60000);
```

And now  I want when anytime I refresh my page manually, Example I'm on 12:20:40 and as We know the rest of seconds is 20 then run the AJAX.

The current If I'm on 12:20:40 then it will run the ajax on 12:21:40

What I want is, If I'm on 12:20:40 then it should run the ajax on 12:21:00

Comment: Wouldn't it be better on server load if everyone wasn't making request at same time?

Comment: Sometimes, I need to refresh it due to some patching code/any technical issue. So When I open the page again it will be on track to refresh it every minute based on rest of second current time

Comment: Should be simple to get current time using Date and use a setTimeout to start your setInterval at next full minute

Comment: @HiDayurieDave check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**easy solution:**

You could check it every second if second was `0` ajax must run.
Try this:

```
setInterval(function()
{
   var second = parseInt((new Date().getTime() / 1000) % 60);
    if(second === 0) {
       $.ajax({
                url: "chkProfile.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:{},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (jsonStr){}
             });
      }
},1000); // or less than 1 sec
```

**optimized solution:**

first calculate how seconds is remained to next minutes and set interval every 60 minutes.

```
   // define fetch data function
   var fetchData  = function(){
       $.ajax({
            url: "chkProfile.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (jsonStr){}
        });
   }

   // begin when dom is ready
   $(document).ready(function(){
      fetchData(); // run fetchData(); here if you want to ajax at first load time
      // get remain time to next minute
      var remainTime = 60 - parseInt((new Date().getTime() / 1000) % 60);
      setTimeout(function(){
         fetchData();
         // redo every minute
         setInterval(fetchData, 60000);
      }, remainTime*1000)
    })
```

Snippet for none ajax example:

```js
// define fetch data function
var fetchData = function() {
  document.write(new Date())
}

// begin when dom is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  fetchData(); // run fetchData(); here if you want to ajax at first load time
  // get remain time to next minute
  var remainTime = 60 - parseInt((new Date().getTime() / 1000) % 60);
  setTimeout(function() {
    fetchData();
    // redo every minute
    setInterval(fetchData, 60000);
  }, remainTime * 1000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, question how to keep the ajax function load the first time when the page loaded?

Comment: I still using the easy solution from your code, is it possible?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave and because of these things optimized solution is 'optimized solution' . You have to block your ajax code to a function like second solution, then run it at first load time.

Comment: Hi if you are on, please have a look on my next question still regarding this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455041/jquery-auto-refresh-every-minute-based-on-current-rest-second-time-and-based-on