# jQuery auto refresh every minute based on current rest second time and based on PC time updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Continuing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362840/jquery-auto-refresh-every-minute-based-on-current-rest-second-time)

I have JS function to refresh by ajax every 60 seconds.

```
var fetchData  = function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "chkProfile.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:
        {
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (jsonStr)
        {
        }
    });
}

fetchData();

var remainTime = 60 - parseInt((new Date().getTime() / 1000) % 60);
setTimeout(function()
{
    fetchData();

    setInterval(fetchData, 60000);
}, remainTime*1000);
```

This function is running OK.
So, the function will run every 60 seconds(1 minute) based on rest of seconds.
Example I refresh the page on 18:51:30 then We now the rest is 30 seconds to go. After meet 60 seconds then run the ajax refresh.

But, facing problem when I try to change date time PC(Raspberry Pi 3) directly.
Example: I set 18:53:40, then I can see the raspberry pc updated. But the function every 60 seconds to be incorrect.

What I want is, whatever I change the time so the JS function know how many seconds rest to be 60 seconds, after meet 60 seconds then run the auto refresh function.

**UPDATED**

After check it, I found the issue is

Example:

```
Time1: Current time: 18:30:15
```

Then I change

```
Time2: To be: 18:30:01
```

The function autorefresh still read the Time1 not Time2 that I changed.
So auto refresh will refresh still based on Time1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
var fetchData  = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "chkProfile.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:
        {
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (jsonStr)
        {
        }
    });
}

fetchData();

setInterval(function(){
   var second = parseInt((new Date().getTime() / 1000) % 60);
    if(second === 0) {
       fetchData();
      }
},1000);
```